# Js with React JS imported is not rendering properly in VS Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I am learning react. I tried to connect JS and HTML. But it is not connecting properly.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="styleesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <div>Hi</div>
);
```

I thought something will be displayed in the screen, but it is not happening in vs code. But I tried the same code in some online coding platforms it worked.

Comment: Why you're not using create-react-app ? It makes life easier

Comment: Is there  any output from the console? Error or message?

Comment: what does "not happening in vs code" mean? VS Code is a tool for writing the code but you can't run client-side JS code there. Have you tried running this in a browser? What happens? Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add react cdn into your HTML. Click [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add React as a plain  tag on an HTML page I recommend giving this a read: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

or instead of doing that
head over to vscode and run a new terminal then type
npx create-react-app myApp
then use the command cd myApp to get into the myApp folder and then use npm start for the react app to start and you edit your app from there

You’ll need to have Node >= 14.0.0 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine.
it's honestly better to use create-react-app

https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app